# Cursor keeps jumping to the top of the email in Outlook 365 online on mobile devices

Tags: browser, outlook

In Outlook 365 through web browsers, if I pause typing an email for a moment, the cursor will jump to the top of the email in front of the salutation. This has been happening for years every time. Not just a pause, but also every few words in the middle of typing. Every few words, I must constantly keep moving the cursor back to where I left off typing and delete the words or half a word that were relocated to before the salutation.

It's unbearable and unusable. I tried multiple phones, browsers from Chrome to others, and even multiple tablets all have the same problem.

How do I stop the cursor from changing position in Outlook on Android mobile devices?